# EFCore 2.2.6 vs 5.0.8 noTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have an application which was originally running on EFCore 2.2.6 and .Net Core 2.1.  We have the below code to query and delete data, it uses AsNoTracking:

```
            var deletedDiag = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<DIAGNOSIS_DETAIL>()
                .GetAll(c => c.Diag.CMS_CASE_ID == model.DiagnosisModel.CASE_ID)
                .Include(i => i.Diag).AsNoTracking().ToList();
            if (deletedDiag != null)
            {
                foreach (var del in deletedDiag)
                {
                    if (!model.SUBDETAILS.Any(a => a.DIAGNOSIS_DETAIL_ID == del.DIAGNOSIS_DETAIL_ID))
                    {
                        _unitOfWork.GetRepository<DIAGNOSIS_DETAIL>().Delete(del);
                    }
                }
            }
```

And Delete does:

```
public void Delete(TEntity entity) => _dbSet.Remove(entity);
```

The deletedDiag query has a include to bring in Diag as a navigational property, above this block of code another query gets the same Diag and marks it for update.

In EFCore 2.2.6 the delete works fine, it's able to update the Diag and then run the delete even though the deletedDiag has a path to it, there are no errors.  In EFCore 5.0.8, we get an error stating that the entity is already being tracked when we try to delete, the fix was to get the deletedDiag to stop tracking it but setting it to null:

```
deletedDiag.ForEach(x => x.Diag = null);
```

that works, but why does it work in 2.2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the capricious path EF-core has taken right from the start in lots of features and defaults. It was impossible to keep track of all changes between versions, even though they were fairly well documented.

One of those changes in v3 onward was in the area of [no-tracking behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#notrackingresolution). In EF-core 2, `AsNoTracking` performed *identity resolution*, which ensures that all occurrences of an entity with a given key in the result set are represented by the same entity instance. In EF-core 3 this was abandoned: each occurrence of the "same" entity now is a new instance.

That means that in EF-core 2, the statements `_dbSet.Remove(entity)` repeatedly marked the *same* `Diag` instance as deleted: i.e. attached it when not yet attached and set its state to `Deleted`. That's not a problem.

EF-core 3+ tries to attach *different* `Diag` instances with the same key, which fails.

Fortunately, in EF core 5 the earlier tracking behavior can be restored by using [`AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotrackingwithidentityresolution?view=efcore-5.0).

```cs
var deletedDiag = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<DIAGNOSIS_DETAIL>()
    .GetAll(c => c.Diag.CMS_CASE_ID == model.DiagnosisModel.CASE_ID)
    .Include(i => i.Diag)
    
    .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()

    .ToList();
```