# Another instance with the key value '' is already being tracked in 1:n relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm trying to update an entity `Tender`, this entity has a List of `TenderOffer` and this `TenderOffer` has a `Company` entity. When I try to update the Tender I'm getting the following error

> Message=The instance of entity type 'Company' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 4}' is
> already being tracked.
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
>
> ```
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore  StackTrace: 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntryentry) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKeykey, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKeykey, InternalEntityEntry entry) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntryentry) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntryentry) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityStateoldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, BooleanmodifyProperties) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityStateentityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties,Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1node) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1node, Func`2 handleNode) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1node, Func`2 handleNode) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1node, Func`2 handleNode) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1node, Func`2 handleNode) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntryrootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityStatestoreGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntryentry, EntityState entityState) 
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Update(TEntity entity) 
>    at DAL.Repositories.TendersRepository.<UpdateTender>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Progetti\DAL\Repositories\TendersRepository.cs:line 613 
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>    at UI.Controllers.TenderController.<SelectTenderWinner>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\Progetti\UI\Controllers\TenderController.cs:line 808
>             
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>                 [External Code] DAL.Repositories.TendersRepository.UpdateTender(ML.Models.Tender) in TendersRepository.cs
>                 [External Code]
>                 UI.Controllers.TenderController.SelectTenderWinner(int,int, bool) in TenderController.cs
> ```

I don't understand why I'm getting this tracking error. I have disabled all tracking behavior of the constructor of the DBContext

```cs
base.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
base.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
base.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

I'm also using AsNoTracking() in all my queries. I can't figure out why EF core is tracking anyway.

The entity_one is "Tender", the entity_two is "TenderOffer"

This is the code in the controller:

```cs
try
{
    //id and winnerOfferID are parameters of the request

    Tender tender = await this._tenderRepository.GetTender(id, false, this.CurrentCompanyID);
    TenderOffer offer = tender.TenderOffers.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == winnerOfferID)
    tender.IsClosed = true;
    tender.ClosureDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    tender.ShowWinner = showWinner;
    tender.WinnerOfferID = winnerOfferID;

    tender.TenderOffers.ForEach(o =>
    {
        if (o.ID == winnerOfferID)
        {
            o.Status = TenderOfferStatus.Winner;
        }
        else
        {
            o.Status = TenderOfferStatus.Rejected;
            o.Company = null;
        }
    });
    
    await this._tenderRepository.UpdateTender(tender);
    
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    return StatusCode(500);
}
```

This is the Update function:

```cs
public async Task<Tender> UpdateTender(Tender tender)
{
        if (tender == null || tender.ID <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot update, tender is null");
        
    this._context.Tenders.Update(tender);

    await this.SaveChangesAsync();

    return tender;
}
```

This is the Get function:

```cs
public async Task<Tender> GetTender(int id, bool skipCompanyCheck = false, int? companyId = null)
{
    IQueryable<Tender> query = this._context.Tenders.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(t => t.Company).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(t => t.Company).ThenInclude(c => c.Logo).AsNoTracking();

        
    //Other include based on parameters, ALSO TENDER OFFERS
    

    tender = await query.Where(tender => tender.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return tender;
}
```

Comment: Just because you disable tracking doesn't mean you can add two entities with the same primary key to a set- what would you like EF to do with that? It can't save them both to a table nor can it decide which one you intend to be the "main" one

Comment: I'm not adding nothing, the "Company" entity tracked is the creator of the "Entity_Two" and when i'm updating the "Entity_One", the company is null, only the companyID of the "Entity_Two" is populated, i'm expecting EF core to update the Entity_One and the list of Entity_Two without changes to the company

Comment: Could you provide the actual code that raises the error. "Entity_One", "Entity_Two" and so on are not very helpful

Comment: I suggest you add all the code... ... where SaveChanges is called

Comment: You first said "entity two has a company entity" then you said "the company id of entity two is populated".. I think we need to see a complete minimum code that demonstrates your issue. It shouldn't require an actual DB

Comment: wouldnt `this._context.Tenders.Update(tender);` need to be called before the changes? reading the common  Summary on that method

Comment: No, but just in case, i've tried your suggestion and I've tried calling the update right after the Get function but the error persist

Comment: include the class Tender  and TenderOffers, and if u have configure the mapping

Comment: I haven't a mapping, the TenderOffers are included but only a range of those based on the users that is trying to view the Tender, where are you suggesting to include the Tender? I'm directly getting the Tender, why should i include the Entity that i'm trying to update?

Comment: You tagged EF6, please pay attention to what the tag guidance says and pick the correct tag (I assume ef-core-6.0).

Comment: Yes, I've updated the tags, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You retrieve tenders without tracking, but the `ChangeTracker` options don't mean that EF is not capable of change tracking anymore. In fact, you count on it being able to track changes, seeing the later modifications and the `SaveChanges` call.

The statement `this._context.Tenders.Update(tender);` marks all objects in the *object graph* (i.e. `tender` and adhering child objects) as `Modified`. The problem is that the graph contains multiple instances of the same `Company`, because multiple `TenderOffer`s refer to the same company.

This causes the exception "another instance with the key value '{ID: 4}' is already being tracked".

It seems fair to assume that EF should know it's the same object, but it doesn't. That has to do with `AsNoTracking` behavior. Since EFC 3.0, `AsNoTracking` is [without *identity resolution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68959575/861716), meaning that when an entity occurs multiple times in a query result, multiple instances of it  are materialized. To change this behavior you should use `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()`. (Only one call in one LINQ statement is sufficient.)

BTW, if you don't  include `Company` and add a nullable `CompanyId` property to `TenderOffer` you could simply set that property to `null`. The current `Update` statement also marks `Company` as `Modified`, which isn't necessary. That could be prevented by first attaching `Company` instances to the context, but setting a `CompanyId` is easier and more light-weight.

Another alternative would be to fetch the data with tracking, modify their properties, and save changes without calling `Update`.

Comment: ^this. OP, you are going through a lot of trouble to try and *avoid* change tracking when your code should work perfectly fine, and be a hell of a lot simpler *with* change tracking. If your code with change tracking was having a problem then I would look to ensure that your DbContext lifetime wasn't set to something like Singleton. It should be PerWebRequest.

Comment: This worked, thanks Gert, i will read some more documentation regarding the design, thanks for suggestions